# How can I answer to a call with Airpods

Tags: call, iphone, airpods

I bought a pair of Airpods for my iPhone 7. When I have them connected I can't answer calls, but I have to disconnect them to be able to answer. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: If you need help in merging accounts, please use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siri can notice when someone is calling you. You can answer the call tapping twice your Airpods. Then, you can tap them twice again to close the call.
If tapping twice doesn't work, go on Settings > Siri and verify "Access when locked" is activated.

Comment: This is odd. I have Siri turned off, and i can answer and hang up calls using the double tap method, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I had to go to settings>general>reset>reset network setting and it worked fine after that